# cx_Freeze throws Missing Modules error

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm aware that these aren't always crucial. However, in my case, when I try to run the program it fails. The error is:

```
Missing modules:
? ElementC14N imported from xml.etree.ElementTree
? OpenSSL imported from CoreEngine.tool_box.cherrypy._cpconfig
? pywintypes imported from CoreEngine.merc_engine.win32
? win32api imported from platform
? win32com.shell imported from CoreEngine.merc_engine.win32
? win32con imported from platform
? win32console imported from CoreEngine.merc_engine.win32
? win32file imported from CoreEngine.merc_engine.win32
? win32gui imported from CoreEngine.merc_engine.win32
? win32pipe imported from platform
? win32process imported from CoreEngine.merc_engine.win32
? winerror imported from CoreEngine.merc_engine.win32
```

I've read in other questions that it's not crucial, but in my case it fails to run. I'm using the included cxfreeze script.
System: Windows 7, Python 2.7.3

Comment: What error do you get when your program fails to run?

Comment: Please include your setup.py.